# Calculate new(x,y) for a line

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

1. Suppose if tanks has to rotate its main gun by $30^\circ$ to hit the target, what will be its new $(x,y)$ coordinate or a formula to calculate it as shown in image?
2. If bullet is fired from the main gun in that direction how to move bullet $((x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2))$ straight to target or what the formula for bullet to travel from main gun to the target?

Just for assumption we can consider line as bullet in image

[image]

What I have tried:

1. $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ to calculate new $(x,y)$ but this is possible only if my circle is at origin.
2. If I get my new $(x,y)$ I will be able to calculate my slope for that line i.e $m=\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$ and then add my slope m each time to move my bullet forward in that direction to hit the target.

Comment: the most efficient way to solve such kinds of problems is to use omogeneous coordinates.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics

Comment: apart from homogenous coordinates is there any other option to solve this problem for example after few google search i came up with formula  X=xcosΘ+ysinΘ and Y=-ysinΘ+xcosΘ i am not sure how much this is correct

Comment: This is the formula for a rotation with center in the origin. But if you car is moving don't work. If you wnt tu use this formula you hve to translate the origin in the point where is the car, and eventually this the same as using omogeneous coordinates.

Comment: thanks and my attempt for second question is right? if i get my new(x,y)  i will be able to calculate my slope for that line i.e m=$\frac{y2−y1}{x2−x1}$ and then add my slope m each time to move my bullet forward in that direction to hit the target

Comment: It seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

It may have already occurred to the poster that one could translate the origin via the equation (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 such that the new origin is the values of (h,k).

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm typing this on my phone making it difficult to respond.

You could also use the 2 dimensional rotation matrix

cosx -sinx
sinx  cosx 
(I see this is being changed from my phone to visual, this is a 2x2 matrix)
Where x is in radians, you can convert to radians via r/d=2pi/360=pi/180
where r is radians and d is degrees.

Once the value is in this matrix, we will be using matrix multiplication in the order of Rp, where R is the rotation matrix and p is the column vector deriving the new point (x,y).

Assuming you have converted 30° to radians we get pi/6.

We then have, 
(root3/2) -(1/2)
(1/2) (root3/2)

x*=[(root3)/2]x-(1/2)y
y*=(1/2)x+[(root3)/2]y

The point (x*,y*) is the new rotated point through 30°.